# makefile loop: easily comment out some items

Tags: bash, loops, makefile

I have a makefile that loops over some items like this:

```
all:
    for i in \
        foo \
        bar \
        baz \
    ; do \
      echo $$i ;\
    done
```

As I'm debugging, I'm often commenting out all but one loop line, but then I need to move these lines above the `for`, or else I get this error:

```sh
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to set this up that allows easily commenting out loop lines within the makefile? Note: I don't want to have to make separate targets for each loop item.

Comment: No.  this is not a makefile issue, this is a shell issue.  If you were to write this at the shell prompt or in a script, you wouldn't have any way to do it either.  Comments in the shell go to the end of the line, so the backslash is ignored as part of the comment, which means the line ends there.

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendations for the same functionality with a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of other ways to do it, it all depends on what you want.  Also since we don't have your actual makefile, just a sample, it's not clear if the actual makefile gives other opportunities to make things better.  I don't know of any way that is objectively completely better than just moving the line in all cases.

One idea, since you are using make, is to pre-create the content of the loop using make variables like this:

```
DATA =
DATA += foo
DATA += bar
DATA += baz

all:
        for i in $(DATA); do \
          echo $$i ;\
        done
```

Now you can comment out the line(s) of `DATA += ...` that you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the line continuation (trailing backslashes) so your recipe is equivalent to:

```
for i in foo bar baz; do echo $$i ; done
```

and you cannot just drop a `#` in the middle of all this, make would ignore the line and you would break your line continuity. You must find a shell compatible way. Example if your shell is bash, and commenting an item consists in prepending a `-`:

```
all:
    @for i in \
        foo \
        -bar \
        baz \
    ; do \
      [[ "$$i" != -* ]] && echo $$i ;\
    done
```

Demo:

```sh
$ make
foo
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a variable, and filter out the unwanted entries:

```
list=foo bar baz

all:
   @for i in $(filter_out bar,$(list)); do \
     echo $$i
```

Comment: This kinda feels like more work than my current solution...?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.    Note that running this with no entries `$(filter_out ,$(list))` would return `$(list)`.   You can also specify multiple entries so you could do `$(filter-out foo bar,$(list))` --  so basically you would be maintaining a list of items you want to exclude as opposed to maintaining a list of things you want to include.

Comment: Also, if you use another variable for things to exclude, you could do something like `$(filter_out $(dont_build),$(list))`.   Doing this, you could specify what you don't want to build on the command line without changing the makefile at all:   `make dont_build=foo`   If you don't specify the `dont_build`, it would default to being empty, and you would build everything.

Comment: Sorry, but that is definitely more work. In the accepted solution, I can highlight all items, use the comment-hotkey in my editor, then go to the item I want to run, and un-comment-hotkey, then build --- no typing required.